# Can I fastboot flash a factory image without flashing the recovery?

Tags: bootloader, fastboot, bootloader-lock, factory-image

[Factory Images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

Using Nexus 9 as an example, the `flash-all.bat` contains:

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-flounder-3.43.0.0114.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul
fastboot -w update image-volantis-lrx21l.zip
```

`image-volantis-lrx21l.zip` contains `recovery.img` and the other images. Can I remove the `recovery.img` to avoid having to re-flash TWRP?

Do I need to use a different parameter for fastboot? ie. not `update` or `-w`?

Comment: No personal experience with that, but doesn't fastboot support flashing single partitions – so you could e.g. extract `system.img` and flash it directly using `fastboot flash system system.img`?

Comment: @Izzy: That may work but there are a few images: (boot, cache, recovery, system, vendor). Is there a similar command for each?

Comment: AFAIK yes. See my answer appearing in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro), you should be able to flash each partition separately – if you've got an image for it. Quoting:

> **Common fastboot commands**
>   `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
>   `fastboot flash boot boot.img`
>   `fastboot flash cache cache.img`
>   `fastboot flash userdata userdata.img`
>   `fastboot flash system system.img`

Following this list come instructions on *Installing recovery using fastboot*, which should apply (with the partition/file names replaced accordingly) be valid for the other partitions. Basically, with [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) activated and your device connected to your computer (which has the appropriate tools installed):

```
# Boot the device into bootloader mode:
adb reboot bootloader

# Make sure fastboot can "see" it:
fastboot devices

# Flash the image:
fastboot flash recovery your_recovery_image.img
```